# How to convert CD to mp3 using Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, mp3, cd

I have Audio CD that I want to convert to mp3 on my laptop with Windows 7.  I am ultimately trying to load onto my android phone. What is the process?  I am a computer neophyte so not able to find instructions on my laptop.

Comment: It's a duplicate of many questions and it's a question seeking a software recommendation which should be closed as "off-topic". Please search for CD ripping software. You'll find plenty of threads here that have already been closed.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an audio CD that I want to convert to MP3 on my laptop with Windows 7.

This requires special software that can convert each CD audio track into audio files (e.g. MP3 files), which can then be stored on the computer. This process is often referred to as *CD ripping*.

> I am ultimately trying to load these files onto my Android phone. What is the process?

For making the MP3 files, the steps are:

1. Place the CD in your computer's CD/DVD drive.
2. Start the software you are using to convert the audio tracks and allow it to read the CD. This may require you to choose which optical drive contains the CD (via the software).
3. Choose an output format (e.g. MP3) and destination for the converted audio files on your computer (again, via the software).
4. Allow the software to convert the audio tracks, following any additional instructions provided by the software (as needed).

Once finished, you can transfer the final audio tracks to the phone.

For converting the CD audio, you can use a program such as [Exact Audio Copy](http://www.exactaudiocopy.de) (which is free for non-commercial home use), though there are many other pieces of software that can do similar things.

For transfering the final MP3 files to the phone, there are a few options depending on what your phone may (or may not) support:

- Depending on the device, some Android phones can simply be connected to a PC via USB cable. This can (potentially) allow you to use the phone's memory card much like an external hard drive. This usually includes allowing e.g. MP3 files to be copied to it from wherever they are stored on your computer.
- For some Android phones, a manufacturer will provide software (perhaps in the form of drivers) you must install to allow the connection described above.
- Some Android phones have removable media cards that can be placed in a computer's media card slot(s), allowing files to be transferred to them before being placed back into the phone.
- In rare cases, where no other options are available, it may be possible to use wireless connections with File Transfer Protocol (FTP) or other wireless standards such as Bluetooth to transfer files.

Unfortunately, each make and model of phone is different, so you will likely have to do a bit of research to discover how your particular model can connect to your computer.